# Is it possible for an editor eg vscode to autosuggest suitable types that conform to a type constraint?

Tags: typescript, dsl, javascript-intellisense

For the following code, when I've supplied a type parameter to the performAs method of the concrete instance `runner` is it possible to get my editor to auto suggest `easyTask` or `hardTask` since they are the only things in scope assignable to the constraint?  Beyond that is it possible within the scope of a project?

eg when I type `runner.performAs([` I would like to see easyTask, hardTask

```
interface Task {
  _type: string;
  perform: () => void;
}

class EasyTask implements Task {
  _type: "easy";
  perform: () => {};
}

class HardTask implements Task {
  _type: "hard";
  perform: () => {};
}

class InvalidTask implements Task {
  _type: "invalid";
  perform: () => {};
}

const easyTask = new EasyTask();
const hardTask = new HardTask();
const invalidTask = new InvalidTask();

type AllowedTasks = HardTask | EasyTask;

class TaskRunner {
  performTasks<T extends Task>(tasks: T[]) {
    tasks.forEach((t) => t.perform());
  }
}

const runner = new TaskRunner();

runner.performTasks<AllowedTasks>([easyTask]);
runner.performTasks<AllowedTasks>([easyTask, invalidTask]); // type error , invalidTask not assignable
```

Comment: Maybe with a [tsserver plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin). They're not very common so I doubt it's been done before. It's definitely possible for them to filter completions, but I don't know how feasible it would be to filter by a type parameter.